# Selecting the first date after the MIN date

Tags: mysql, sql

This site has answered many a SQL questions for me. Finally signed up to ask one of my own and get active here.

Anyways, I'm working in a table that has Date_Effective and Date_Lapse. A Client can have multiple rows so what I'm trying to get to is the number of days between a Date_Lapse and the next Date_Effective for the same client. The date values in this table are int's that I'll convert to dates later.

The below code doesn't work. It doesn't like the second value I'm joining on. Why can't I get it to give me min date_effective that's greater than each date_effective? If I run the below I just get no results because it's seeing it as there are no effective dates greater than the min effective date.

```
SELECT ClientID, c1.Date_Lapse, c2.Date_Effective
FROM Fact_Episodes c1
LEFT JOIN (     
            SELECT ClientID, min(Date_Effective) as Date_Effective
            FROM Fact_Episodes 
            GROUP BY ClientID
          ) c2
ON c1.ClientID = c2.ClientID
AND c2.Date_Effective > c1.Date_Effective
```

Comment: Before I was trying it this way I was trying to get it to work via partioned row numbers and I couldn't get it so that's when i started trying by the dates themselves and now after I post this I figured out what I was doing wrong with my partition of course haha thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to stick with the left join, this would work.

```
select c1.ClientID, c1.Date_Lapse, min(c2.Date_Effective) as Date_Effective
from Fact_Episodes c1
  left join Fact_Episodes c2
    on c1.ClientID = c2.ClientID
   and c2.Date_Effective > c1.Date_Effective
group by c1.ClientId, c1.Date_Lapse
```

Comment: The subquery for `c2` is unnecessary and undesirable in MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can't delete this until you post the better solution for Tim to accept. Please do

Comment: @SqlZim . . . I'm only suggesting that you edit the answer.  Your answer is reasonable and correct . . . only less efficient because of how MySQL implements subqueries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand, I was just hoping for more information on the performance impact of how MySQL implements subqueries.

Comment: @SQLZim . . . I believe that MySQL always materializes subqueries in the `FROM` clause.  This incurs overhead in writing the data.  More importantly, it prevents the use of indexes (and partitions).  The "believe" is because the newest version of MySQL may be improving the underlying engine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Wow, I did not know that. It looks like the beta reference manual still says the same thing for the upcoming latest version, beta draft is marked as updated yesterday: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-optimization.html